# Resolving ambiguous categories in an ordered list

Tags: algorithm, math, function

Let's take a concrete example and hope I can be clear. Suppose the (ordered) list of months:

> January < February < March < ... <
>   December

(with integers that stand for the months, zero-based), such that

> Jan is 0, Feb is 1, ..., Dec is 11.

Now suppose I do not have access to the full names of months, and am given the following list, where months have been shortened to their first letter, and *e* stands for an empty category, like this:

> e, F, e, e, e

If I build a list of "unambiguous months" (f:1, s:8, o:9, n:10, d:11), I can fill the empty categories by by first calculating the first category (using subtraction and mod 12), and then write the rest from there. However, suppose I am given the list

> e, A, e, e, J, e

Then I can (intuitively) calculate that although *A* is ambiguous (could be April or August), in this context it can only be April, since August does not have any *J*s following it after 2 categories. Once I find this, I can again calculate everything from the start.

My question, finally, is: is there an analytic solution (function, algorithm) for this problem, or is my only hope to use brute force to define each potential relation? For some examples, no disambiguation algorithm/function can work: consider the case where I have a *J* followed by 11 *e*'s, followed by a *J* followed by 11 *e*'s ... Since there is a year in between, I cannot disambiguate *J* into January, June or July.

**Answer**: I ended up coding Il-Bhima's answer, because for this case in particular,  regex's are ok, even at a higher running time O(mn). However, I accepted Ben's answer as the correct answer because it subsumes the others (mentions the regex solution), but also suggests a better way by using the KMP algorithm O(m+n), although this is for larger numbers of the string against to match the pattern. Thanks, everybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could use a modified [KMP string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm) to solve this problem.

The modification would be to match anything against the empty category. It could even find all possible values for you, such as the J with 11 e's like you mentioned.

You could also use a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine) to determine possibilities, this is what a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) would do.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Could you please expand on how you see KMP would find the values for my "J"s example? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of doing this is using regular expressions.  Suppose you want to match `e, A, e, e, J, e`.

Construct the following regular expression: `r = ".A..J."`

Let `c` be our control string:

```
  c = "JFMAMJJASONDJFMAMJJASOND"
```

Now we search for all matches of `r` in the string `c` where the starting index of a match is within the first half of `c`.

In general, this may not be the most efficient method.  The most naive solution, attempting to match the pattern with every cyclic shift of the control string `"JFMAMJJASOND"` runs in `O(nm)` time, where `n` is the length of the pattern, `m` is the length of the control string (in our case `JFMAMJJASOND`).

Answer (score 2):

We can build on Il-Bhima's answer a little for the general case.  First, we recognize that the only truly ambiguous pairs of A, M, or J are two J's that are six months apart or two of the same letter that are a year apart.  Any other combination will yield an unambiguous match in the control string.  (I built a table of all possible combinations to prove that.)

So all you need out of your entire starting list is two months whose distance mod 12 isn't 0 or 6.  You can then build a small regular expression to match against the control string.  Alternatively, you could build a lookup table containing the ordered pair and the distances between the months.